# There is an implant in me, is there a way to identify the frequency it is receiving signals on?

Tags: signal-analysis, audio, signal-detection

There is an implant in me, is there a way to identify the frequency it is receiving signals on?

I don't want to share the evidence and my reasoning for believing there is an implant in me, you can either take my word for it or not.

I want to find the frequency it is receiving signals on, so far I have used dvb-t dongle to use it as an SDR, and I have manually scanned the entire frequency range provided by it, which is 24MHz to 1700MHz, which was very tiring, but I couldn't identify anything suspicious, it could be possible that as I was tuning, the frequency it was receiving signals on was not the tuned one.

I want to know if there a way to identify the frequency of the signal? How? And what equipment would I need?

Comment: Is is receiving only, or does it transmit too?

Comment: @LaurentDuval It is a receiving only.

Comment: Standard aliminum kitchen foil can provide an effective electromagnetic shield. Use multiple folds. Do not leave gaps. Try with cellular phone and see that it blocks the received & transmitted signals.

Comment: My friend Eric, who is an EE, DSPer, and communications specialist was curious which vaccine you may have had.

Answer (score 2):

It is very hard to detect a device that is passively receiving a signal, and even more so when it is designed to operate undetected. Some random comments and ideas:

- In the UK one has to pay taxes on TV ownership. I read somewhere that they employed a technique to detect unlicensed TVs, which are otherwise passive receivers. I don't know how the technique works, but you may want to research it.
- Scanning the spectrum around you is useless. There are hundreds of different signals around us all the time; it will be impossible to detect if any one of them is intended for your implant.
- Any receiver must use metal components, so you could use a metal detector on yourself. Get a very small receiver (such as one of the tiny WiFi dongles) and verify that your metal detector can detect it on the other side of your head; it should then be able to detect any device inside your body.

Comment: Good thought on the metal detector, this is part of what I was trying to get at with the X-ray idea but a metal detector is certainly more practical and safe

Comment: I've researched the techniques which were used by UK to identify illegal TVs, they are mentioned on this Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TV_detector_van. But most of them rely on the television screens behavior, only one relied on local oscillator, but I think implant in me, if it has one, will require a very sensitive antenna and equipment to be detected by a make-shift SDR.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. And yes, as I said, detecting the presence of a passive receiver is very difficult.

Answer (score 1):

It is very difficult to answer this question directly because there is not much information available. It's almost more of a reverse engineering question, because you are trying to discover how a device you do not have full knowledge of works.

Nevertheless, I can suggest some things that it might help you think about:

0. When you say the device does not transmit, do you mean that it does not send out data without first being 'asked to' by another device / transmitter? Or that it does not ever send out data at all? If it is the latter, then it will be almost impossible to discover anything useful.
1. Think of what technologies could be used to actually implement communications, and what frequencies they use. For example: [Wi-Fi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels), [Bluetooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#Implementation), [NFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near-field_communication#Design).
2. What other device would the implant normally be expected to receive signals from?
3. What size is the device? If you know where the device is implanted, and depending on how serious you are, getting an X-ray could help you to discover this.
4. Is the implant powered? If so, how? The less power available, the more limited are the possible communication options. If the implant is unpowered, the only way I can imagine it would communicate would be as a passive RFID device.

If you are able to answer any of these questions, then we may be able to help you further. You could also ask on https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Answers to your questions: 0 ans: It never transmits. 1 ans: I don't know if it uses standard technologies like NFC, Bluetooth or WiFi. 2 ans: I don't know. 3 ans: It is probably small enough to be fit in my auditory system or cause bone conduction. 4 ans: It could be field powered. I'll try your reverse engineering suggestion in the mean time.

Comment: If the device never transmits then what does it do? And how do you know that it actually has the capability to receive data?

Comment: I've already answered this in my OP, I believe I've clarified it with these words: "I don't want to share the evidence and my reasoning for believing there is an implant in me, you can either take my word for it or not." And to answer your question about what it does, it emits sounds or causes vibrations on bone which can be perceived as sound, although I never heard anything.

Comment: I am not questioning the existence of your implant, I am asking how you know that it can receive data.

Comment: As I said based on my experience. It could only be explained if it was receiving signals which it is emitting as audio or vibrations on bone. I'm unable to post this question on reverse engineering stack exchange because the tags there are suitable for this topic.

Comment: What exactly could be explained? Sorry if these questions are annoying but I'm doing my best to understand what's going on so I can help you. On reverse engineering SE you could try the tag [radio-interception].

Comment: Some of the things in my life can only be explained by an implant. That is all I can say on this. I'll try posting this on reverse engineering with the tag you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

i dunno, [something like this product](https://www.spyguy.com/collections/bug-detectors/products/t-9-specialty-rf-detector) might help.

you need to find yourself a good Faraday Cage or construct one.  maybe you could build a small cubical room out of wood and cardboard that is 2 meters on a side.  line the entire interior with good aluminum foil, make sure the adjacent pieces are well connected with multiple fold contact.  connect that to a good earth ground.

place a chair in the Faraday cage and sit it in with your RF detector and scan your body carefully from toe to head on several front and back and left and right side stripes.  do that very carefully twice, then remain sitting in the seat and do it again approximately 10 minutes later.  then again about 15 minutes later.

this does not insure that you're not bugged, the implant could be off most of the time and then at random times might boot up, take your readings and, if there is the right kinda WIFI or 5G network, can send the data to an predetermined IP address.  this is how trojan horses work.  the IP address is buried in the code of the trojan horse and they pop out their data at times you might be least likely to detect.